# Using Highlight.js inside a node script?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, jsdom, highlight.js

Attempting to run [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) inside a node script that uses [JSDom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) to select the block that needs to be highlighted.

```
          const dom = new JSDOM(html);
          const document = dom.window.document;

          document.querySelectorAll('.Test_markup > code').forEach((node)=> {
            var markup = node.innerHTML;
            console.log(markup);
            highlight.highlightBlock(markup);
          });
```

The logged markup looks like this:

```
          <div class="Grid">
              <!-- Use Nunjucks to keep markup DRY -->

                  <div class="Grid_cell">1/2</div>

                  <div class="Grid_cell">2/2</div>

           </div>
```

When I run the code on the markup the result is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Thoughts?

Comment: On what line does said error occur? What is the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will produce the highlight:

```
 const highlight = require('highlight.js');
 console.log(highlight.highlight('html', markup).value);
```